# How to lock unwanted IPs in the .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ip

In most cases, the .htacess seems to lock out unwanted visitors from my site.
But some bad boys are able to penetrate my .htacess protection.
Example:
The bad boy is has the IP 46.161.11.xx  .
So I wrote into the .htaccess file:

```
Require not ip 46.161.11.
```

But this did not help.
So I changed it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^46\.161\.11\.([1-9]?\d|[12]\d\d)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

But this does not help, too.

Is there a more effective IP lock in Apache?
Thx in advance for your hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be my solution:

```
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 46\.161\.11\.
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```